# How to change/add/edit Info.plist in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, info.plist

I have a serious question that I didn't find the answer to.

I have a Flutter app and needed to use a dependency and in its docs, it says this

*Setup iOS Info.plist* And the docs have this code:-

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<true/>
```

Where is that file? I can't seem to find it! Also if it doesn't exist can you help me create it in the right path? Thanks in Advance

The link to the DOCS for more information:- https://pub.dev/packages/easy_web_view#-readme-tab-

Comment: It should be in `ios/Runner/Info.plist`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The info.plist file is found in the IOS module of your flutter project(ios/Runner/info.plist):

[image]

If you have Xcode, you can just right click on your root directory and click on Flutter --> Open ios module in XCode.

[image]

Once you do that Xcode will open up and you'll clearly see the info.plist file under the Runner file:

[image]